# How to set dynamic where clause with JSStore while working with IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am working on IndexedDB using JsStore wrapper. Everything works fine in the code when I set the column name directly in the Where block but if I make it dynamic as shown in the following code then the code doesn't work.

```
var searchValueType = $('input:radio[name=searchValueType]:checked').val();
var searchValue = $("#searchValue").val();                
var column1 = 'Name';
var whereClause = column1+':'+searchValue;
alert ("where clause >> "+whereClause);
DbConnection.select({
    From: "Student",    
     Where: {
        whereClause
      },
    }, 
    function (students) {
    var HtmlString = "";
    students.forEach(function (student) {
        HtmlString += "<tr ItemId=" + student.Id + "><td>" +
            student.Name + "</td><td>" +
            student.Gender + "</td><td>" +
            student.Country + "</td><td>" +
            student.City + "</td><td>" +
            "<a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" +
            "<td><a href='#' class='delete''>Delete</a></td>";
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    $('#tblGrid tbody').html(HtmlString);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is clearly visible in code, Where expects an object but you are passing a string within curly bracket.

You need to create the object in a variable and assign it to Where option of jsstore.

Please check the below code -

```
var searchValueType = $('input:radio[name=searchValueType]:checked').val();
var searchValue = $("#searchValue").val();
//var column1 = 'Name';
//var whereClause = column1+':'+searchValue;

//alert ("where clause >> "+whereClause);

// Where clause is now an object
var whereClause = {
    Name: searchValue
}
DbConnection.select({
    From: "Student",
    Where: whereClause,
}, function(students) {
    var HtmlString = "";
    students.forEach(function(student) {
        HtmlString += "<tr ItemId=" + student.Id + "><td>" +
            student.Name + "</td><td>" +
            student.Gender + "</td><td>" +
            student.Country + "</td><td>" +
            student.City + "</td><td>" +
            "<a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" +
            "<td><a href='#' class='delete''>Delete</a></td>";
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    $('#tblGrid tbody').html(HtmlString);
});
```